# Bluetooth characteristic being set to nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, macos, bluetooth

I am running an app that communicates from my Mac to my iPhone via bluetooth and vice versa. It is all working perfectly (with two generated characteristics one from Mac to iPhone and one from iPhone to Mac) apart from, occasionally my characteristic from mac to iPhone is not being updated and I think this is due to the charachteristic on the mac being set to nil for no apparent reason.

So to update my char on my Mac I do:

```
- (void)updateValueForCharacteristic:(int)sendID {
    NSLog(@"sent %d", sendID);
    
    if (self.characteristic != nil) {
        dispatch_block_t block = ^(void) {
            NSData *value = [NSData dataWithBytes:&sendID length:sizeof(sendID)];
            [_managerout updateValue:value forCharacteristic:self.characteristic onSubscribedCentrals:nil];
        };
        
        dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
        dispatch_async(queue, block);
    }else{
        //why is this sometimes being called?!
    }
}
```

and to receive on the iPhone I do:

```
- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic error:(NSError *)error {
    if (error != nil) {
        NSLog(@"Error updating value: %@", error.localizedDescription);
        
        return;
    }
    
    CBUUID *characteristicUUID = [CBUUID UUIDWithString:_kCharacteristicUUIDin];
    NSInteger rec = 0;
    [characteristic.value getBytes:&rec length:sizeof(rec)];
    NSLog(@"recieved %ld", (long)rec);
    
    if ([characteristic.UUID isEqual:characteristicUUID]) {
        NSLog(@"officially recieved %ld", (long)rec);
        //handle char (sometimes not noticing)
    }
}
```

Is there anyway that I can verify that my iPhone has received the char. Also should I scrap this technique and try with writing (rather than updating) the char or maybe try with multiple chars rather than just the one?

I really need to make sure that the iPhone gets it or else the program is useless.

## update

I have added an `else` block to `if (self.characteristic != nil) {` and the else block is being called when my char isn't being updated!!! But I can't find for the life of my why the self.characteristic is being set to nil?! And also how should I go about re-creating the characteristic after?

## [project](https://mega.nz/#!7hVSTJYJ!zzLztG8XgxgX-3633HJyC7po0smkX4TfhTtIwXMbJPQ)

Comment: What are the roles of your devices?  iPhone is central and Mac is peripheral?  Or do both devices implement both roles?  A central can issue a write with response to get confirmation of the write but a peripheral can only issue a notify which is best-effort.  Generally the notify should be reliable unless the radio environment/distance is marginal.  Are you notifying too quickly?

Comment: Both but in this case I am mainly interested in the Mac acting as the central and the iPhone the peripheral. What does "unless the radio environment/distance is marginal" So are you recommending changing to write rather than update?

Comment: The code you have shown here has the peripheral sending data to the central.  If you want feedback as to whether the 'write' was successful then you need the central to issue a write with notify to the peripheral.  A notify isn't guaranteed but generally it should be reliable if the devices are nearby.  The other issue I could think of is that you issue two notifies quickly, the data from the first will be lost if it hasn't been processed by the central; GATT isn't a stream, it is like variables. If I set A to 1 and then set it to 2 before some other code reads it, all it will see is 2

Comment: But using the "didUpdateValueForCharacteristic" on the iphones side should call for every update? Anyway I am definitely not sending two updates to the char at the same. I really hate this issue it is driving me crazy. Strange thing is, is that the iPhone always picks up the updates when connected via USB to my mac. I am now going to try the write method. And on failed write, write again.

Comment: @Paulw11 can you see the update!

Comment: Can you show the code where you set the characteristic in the first place?

Comment: @Aris here is a zip to the project on the mac and iphone https://mega.nz/#!7hVSTJYJ!zzLztG8XgxgX-3633HJyC7po0smkX4TfhTtIwXMbJPQ